# MIPS data hazards

Tags: mips

I am trying to figure out what the data hazards for this code would be...

```
lw $15, 8                      # load num (8) into register $15
lw $16, 0                      # load sum (0) into register $16
lw $17, array              # load array into register $14
 lw $14, 2                     # load sub value(2) into register $14
while:
 beq $15, $zero exitLoop   # loop for; while(num>=0) statement  
 add $16, $16, $15     # sum = sum + num
 sub $15, $15, $14               # num = num – 2
j while
exitLoop:  sw $16, 12($17)             # array[3] = sum; the fourth element in array is set to the sum
```

Looking for the data hazards; where they occur and why

Comment: It is not a matter of getting errors I am just looking to understand data hazards better. For this set of code I am trying to determine where the data hazards would be. I was thinking that it would be with register $15 because it would have to be forwarded from the sub instruction to the beq instruction but I am just not sure I am looking at this correctly

Comment: I do not see any data hazard in your code. Even on $15, with the jump delay, there is no need of forwarding. But your starting `lw` are weird. What makes you think that you can know the addresses of your data in memory before linking? Always use labels instead. And what is `array`? If if is the address of a table, then the `lw $17, array` loads array[0] is $17 and the final `sw`is incorrect. And if you want the final `sw` to store at `array[3]`, then you should use a `la $17,array`, instead of a `lw`.